# How to visualize given temperatures' data with layer in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, data-visualization

I have some data in a .csv file with the format:

```
longitude latitude temperature
```

Need to visualize those temps on a heatmap-like layer above the GoogleMaps map.

Have tried the [heatmaps offered by the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap) (which also offers the use of weights for each spot), but didn't work out as I would like it to. Moreover, even with a small portion of my data it was pretty slow. (There are about 80.000 entries in the .csv)

I also considered using google's Fusion Tables, but I believe this wouldn't help either.

I would like an end result like the one [here](http://www.temperatur.nu/karta.html) or **even better something like [that](http://maps.forum.nu/gm_heatmap.html)**.

**[Here](http://openweathermap.org/help/tiles.html?opacity=0.4&l=temp) is another very nice end-result example.**

Let me clarify that I am interested in the heatmap-style layer and not the clustering.

Thank you!

//EDIT: since one of the links seems to have some issues, here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It has been a while since you've asked this question. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: No, that project was finished but without any solution that applies to the question :/

Answer (score 0):

May be you can look at [gmap3](http://gmap3.net/), they have some tools to do "clustering" as shown in [this example.](http://gmap3.net/en/pages/19-demo/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am interested in the a heatmap-like visualization, not the clustering of points/markers